# ODE: $\dot{x}=f(t)x^2,x(0)=1$ solution on $\mathbb{R}\Leftrightarrow\int_{0}^{t}f(s)ds<1\forall t\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a continuous function and $\phi$ a solution on its maximal interval of existence for the initial value problem
>   $$
> \dot{x}=f(t)x^2\hspace{0.3cm},\hspace{0.3cm}x(0)=1
> $$
>   Show that the solution exists on $\mathbb{R}$ iff
>   $$
> \int_{0}^{t}f(s)ds<1\hspace{0.3cm}\forall t\in\mathbb{R}
> $$

So what I think would be the right way to start is to note that $\dfrac{\dot{x}}{x^2}=-\dfrac{d}{dt}\dfrac{1}{x}$ however that only works when $x\neq 0$ so I'm not quite sure about how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right-hand side
$$
F(t, x) = f(t) x^2
$$
is *locally Lipschitz continuous* in $x$, so that every solution of an initial value problem
$$
 \dot x = F(t, x(t)) \, , \quad x(t_0) = x_0
$$
on an interval is *unique.*  It follows that for every solution on an interval, either $x(t) \equiv 0$ or  $x(t)$ has no zeros.

In your case $x(0) = 1$ so that $x(t) \ne 0$ (actually: $x(t) > 0$)  on the maximal interval of existence, and you can proceed by integrating $\frac{\dot{x}}{x^2}$ (i.e. by a “separation of variables”): If a solution on $\Bbb R$ exists then
$$ \tag{*}
\int_{0}^{t} f(s) \,ds = \int_{0}^{t}\frac{\dot x(s)}{x^2(s)} \, ds
= 1 - \frac{1}{x(t)}  
$$
is less than one.

And if  $\int_{0}^{t} f(s) \,ds < 1$ for all $t$ then $(*)$ can be solved for $x(t)$ to get a solution on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: What would go wrong if $x(t)$ would have zeros ?

Comment: @ChristianSinger: You could not compute $\int_{0}^{t}\frac{\dot x(s)}{x^2(s)} \, ds$ if $x(t)$ has a zero in $[0, t]$.

Comment: Oh I see. I should refrase my question to why can't $x(t)$ have zeros or must be equal to $0$ on an interval.

Comment: @ChristianSinger: If $x(t_0) = 0$ for some $t_0$ then both $x$ and the zero function are solutions of the IVP $\dot x = F(t, x), x(t_0) = 0$. And since solutions are unique, $x$ must be the zero function.

Comment: Ah now I see. I Appreciate your help!